# writing firefox extension : youtube error

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, youtube, firefox-addon

I am writing an extension to change my videos ad breaks and I am doing it with these codes, but I get an error, the video ad breaks are changing and saving then coming out and when i looked again. The record is not handled. I am waiting for your help about it

jquery code:

```
$('.field-midrolls-manual')[0].val("08:00");
```

javascript code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("field-midrolls-manual")[0].value ="08:00";
```

Comment: Im a little bit confused, can you reword please.

Comment: This question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) **the desired behavior**; B) **a specific problem or error** *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Hi there bkir were you able to solve this?